# How to implement a network data fetch and then display in checkbox in alert inside showDialog with setState

Tags: flutter

I couldn't find a way to fetch data from network API inside showDialog > StatefulBuilder > AlertDialog. After fetching, this data should display in checkboxes and then finally on click ok, the selected checkboxes data is returned to the parent widget. There are more states other than these checkbox states in the alert. But the `Navigator.of(context).pop()` can return only single value.

Is there a way to rebuild the StatefulBuilder with setState on parent widget. Or some easy hack to rebuild the StatefulBuilder from an outside function like `fetchOrderStatus()` in the below code. (might be possible with a key on StatefulBuilder, but don't know how).

Below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:recase/recase.dart';
import 'package:woocommerceadmin/src/orders/widgets/OrderDetailsPage.dart';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';

class OrdersListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String baseurl;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  OrdersListPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.baseurl,
    @required this.username,
    @required this.password,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrdersListPageState createState() => _OrdersListPageState();
}

class _OrdersListPageState extends State<OrdersListPage> {
  String baseurl;
  String username;
  String password;
  List ordersListData = List();
  int page = 1;
  bool hasMoreToLoad = true;
  bool isListLoading = false;

  bool isSearching = false;
  String searchValue = "";

  String sortOrderByValue = "date";
  String sortOrderValue = "desc";

  bool isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
  bool isOrderStatusOptionsError = false;
  String orderStatusOptionsError;
  Map<String, bool> orderStatusOptions = {};

  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    baseurl = widget.baseurl;
    username = widget.username;
    password = widget.password;
    fetchOrdersList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: _myAppBar(),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        onRefresh: handleRefresh,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                  if (hasMoreToLoad &&
                      !isListLoading &&
                      scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
                          scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
                    handleLoadMore();
                  }
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: ordersListData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => OrderDetailsPage(
                                  id: ordersListData[index]["id"],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          _orderDate(ordersListData[index]),
                                          _orderIdAndBillingName(
                                              ordersListData[index]),
                                          _orderStatus(ordersListData[index]),
                                          _orderTotal(ordersListData[index])
                                        ]),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ]),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
            if (isListLoading)
              Container(
                height: 60.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                    child: SpinKitFadingCube(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  size: 30.0,
                )),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchOrderStatus() async {
    String url =
        "$baseurl/wp-json/wc/v3/reports/orders/totals?consumer_key=$username&consumer_secret=$password";
    setState(() {
      isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
      isOrderStatusOptionsError = false;
    });
    dynamic response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (json.decode(response.body) is List &&
            !json.decode(response.body).isEmpty) {
          json.decode(response.body).forEach((item) {
            if (item is Map) {
              orderStatusOptions.putIfAbsent(item["slug"], () => false);
            }
          });
          setState(() {
            isOrderStatusOptionsReady = true;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
            isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
            orderStatusOptionsError = "Failed to fetch order status options";
          });
        }
      } else {
        String errorCode = "";
        if (json.decode(response.body) is Map &&
            json.decode(response.body).containsKey("code") &&
            json.decode(response.body)["code"] is String) {
          errorCode = json.decode(response.body)["code"];
        }
        setState(() {
          isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
          isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
          orderStatusOptionsError =
              "Failed to fetch order status options. Error: $errorCode";
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
        isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
        orderStatusOptionsError =
            "Failed to fetch order status options. Error: $e";
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _myAppBar() {
    Widget myAppBar;

      myAppBar = AppBar(
        title: Text("Orders List"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isSearching = !isSearching;
              });
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
            ),
            onTap: _orderFilter,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return myAppBar;
  }

  void _orderFilter() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          // fetchOrderStatus();  
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Sort & Filter"),
              titlePadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 0),
              content: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 400,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Sort by",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
                                value: sortOrderByValue,
                                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                  FocusScope.of(context)
                                      .requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                  setState(() {
                                    sortOrderByValue = newValue;
                                  });
                                },
                                items: <String>[
                                  "date",
                                  "id",
                                  "title",
                                  "slug",
                                  "include"
                                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(
                                      value.titleCase,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_downward,
                                color: (sortOrderValue == "desc")
                                    ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                    : Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                sortOrderValue = "desc";
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_upward,
                                color: (sortOrderValue == "asc")
                                    ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                    : Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                sortOrderValue = "asc";
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Filter by",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Order Status",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      isOrderStatusOptionsReady
                          ? ListView(
                              children:
                                  orderStatusOptions.keys.map((String key) {
                                return new CheckboxListTile(
                                  title: Text(key),
                                  value: orderStatusOptions[key],
                                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      orderStatusOptions[key] = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            )
                          : Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: SpinKitFadingCube(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  size: 30.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 0),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Close"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options

1. Fetch the data before showing the dialog. Using either async/await keywords or `.then`, you wait for the fetching of data to complete, then use the data in the dialog

```
void _orderFilter() async {
    await fetchOrderStatus();
    showDialog(...); //Use the response in the dialog
}
```

2. Create a new stateful widget for the dialog and have `fetchOrderStatus()` be a method in that class. This allows you to have more control over what to display as well as state changes in the dialog.

Comment: I can't use the 1st approach as I need to show dialog after icon button press.

The 2nd approach is rather useful but can't figure out then how to pass selected data back to other widget.

Comment: @Gauravjain You can. Just insert that code snippet into the function that triggers after the button press. If you include your button press code into your question, I can edit my answer to follow that format

Comment: @Gauravjain modified the code snippet. It now uses async/await since you use that in your code.

Comment: I understand that I could display the alert when data is ready. But actually I want the opposite of that. The idea is that when I click the button, The dialog opens, call fetchOrderStatus asynchronous and then show the value when the data is ready. There will be loading shown in alert till the data is ready.  The problem is that setState of class can't affect the dialog box.

Comment: @Gauravjain In that case you would have to go for the second option. What you want to do requires the dialog to have its own state.

Comment: Is there no way to trigger a rebuild of StatefulBuilder from inside fetchOrderStatus() function after I call setState() using statefulBuilder key. All other things are working great.

Comment: @Gauravjain Unfortunately no, not that I know of. You cannot dynamically "rebuild" something that does not have its own state. Also, by shifting the dialog code to another class, your current code would become much shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

@gaurav-jain I have followed your question from Github where you asked a question about my answer to this problem. How I did it is i have a button that when clicked immediately opens the dialog that then waits for the Future to load data from the API: The `async` function `_showOptions()` renders the dialog that renders a list of checkboxes with options fetched from API:

```
new RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.green,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        onPressed: () {
          if (state._isLoading){
            // don't do anything when form is submitting and this button is pressed again
            return null;
          }
          else {
            if (state._formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              state._showOptions().then((selected){
                print(state.selectedOptions);
                if (state.selectedOptions.isNotEmpty) {
                  _submitForm();
                }
                else {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text('You have not selected any option'),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text('OK'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  );
                }
              });
            }
            else {
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Your form has errors. Rectify them and submit again'),
                )
              );
            }
          }

        },
        child: Text(state._isLoading ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),
```

The `state` here is the parent widget's state, but the async dialog has it's own state to make it work. You can refer back to the github comment for the other pieces of the code here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15194#issuecomment-450490409

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @wxker, 2nd approach, I have implemented other stateful widget which returns AlertDialog.

Parent Widget Calling showDialog on tap:

```
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return OrdersListFiltersModal(
                    baseurl: widget.baseurl,
                    username: widget.username,
                    password: widget.password,
                    sortOrderByValue: sortOrderByValue,
                    sortOrderValue: sortOrderValue,
                    orderStatusOptions: orderStatusOptions,
                    onSubmit:
                        (sortOrderByValue, sortOrderValue, orderStatusOptions) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.sortOrderByValue = sortOrderByValue;
                        this.sortOrderValue = sortOrderValue;
                        this.orderStatusOptions = orderStatusOptions;
                      });
                      handleRefresh();
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Child stateful widget returning alert with default value and function callback in constructor to change parent widget state.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Sort & Filter"),
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 0),
      content: Container(
        height: 400,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Sort by",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
                          value: sortOrderByValue,
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                            setState(() {
                              sortOrderByValue = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: <String>[
                            "date",
                            "id",
                            "title",
                            "slug",
                            "include"
                          ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(
                                value.titleCase,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_downward,
                          color: (sortOrderValue == "desc")
                              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                              : Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          sortOrderValue = "desc";
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_upward,
                          color: (sortOrderValue == "asc")
                              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                              : Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          sortOrderValue = "asc";
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "Filter by",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(
                  "Order Status",
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .body1
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              isOrderStatusOptionsError
                  ? Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                            child: Text(
                              orderStatusOptionsError,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : isOrderStatusOptionsReady
                      ? Column(
                          children: orderStatusOptions.keys.map((String key) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  orderStatusOptions[key] =
                                      !orderStatusOptions[key];
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                height: 30,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Checkbox(
                                      value: orderStatusOptions[key],
                                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          orderStatusOptions[key] = value;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        key.titleCase,
                                        style:
                                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        )
                      : Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: SpinKitPulse(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 15, 0),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Close"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Ok"),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onSubmit(
                sortOrderByValue, sortOrderValue, orderStatusOptions);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchOrderStatusOptions() async {
    String url =
        "${widget.baseurl}?consumer_key=${widget.username}&consumer_secret=${widget.password}";
    setState(() {
      isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
      isOrderStatusOptionsError = false;
    });
    http.Response response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (json.decode(response.body) is List &&
            !json.decode(response.body).isEmpty) {
          Map<String, bool> tempMap = orderStatusOptions;
          json.decode(response.body).forEach((item) {
            if (item is Map &&
                item.containsKey("slug") &&
                item["slug"] is String &&
                item["slug"].isNotEmpty) {
              tempMap.putIfAbsent(item["slug"], () => false);
            }
          });
          setState(() {
            isOrderStatusOptionsReady = true;
            orderStatusOptions = tempMap;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
            isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
            orderStatusOptionsError = "Failed to fetch order status options";
          });
        }
      } else {
        String errorCode = "";
        if (json.decode(response.body) is Map &&
            json.decode(response.body).containsKey("code") &&
            json.decode(response.body)["code"] is String) {
          errorCode = json.decode(response.body)["code"];
        }
        setState(() {
          isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
          isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
          orderStatusOptionsError =
              "Failed to fetch order status options. Error: $errorCode";
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        isOrderStatusOptionsReady = false;
        isOrderStatusOptionsError = true;
        orderStatusOptionsError =
            "Failed to fetch order status options. Error: $e";
      });
    }
  }
}
```